# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when using AudioPlayer in Swift 2

Tags: swift, option-type

Hi I am trying to play a music file with a following code in swift 2. Basically I just dragged the audio file with a name f.mp3 to the asses folder and it my code breaks with the following message: 
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Where exactly I need to put my mp3 file so the IOS can find it. Thank you

```
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer! = nil
func playMyFile() {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("f", ofType: "mp3")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
     try audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.play()

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code is working fine with my project and here is my complete code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playMyFile()
    }

    func playMyFile() {

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("f", ofType: "mp3")
        let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        do {
            try audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Make sure your audio is added into Copy Bundle Resources like this:

[image]

If not added then add it this way:

[image]

Check [THIS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=14961133122178116931) sample for more Info.

Comment: thank you very much!!!! btw i had to rename a file because it was telling me that i can not added it because the file with such a name already exist.

Comment: open project folder and remove old file first.. and add new file again..:)

Comment: Happy to help you..:)